# How to find out all custom fields, LWC/Aura/VF, apex classes and triggers required in a Lightning Community?

Tags: lightning-community, scratch-org, unlocked-package, scratch-org-definition-file

I would like to include a Lightning community (ExperienceBundle, Network and Custom Site) in an unlocked package so as to be able to develop codes using scratch orgs as well as have it in CI/CD pipeline.

Question: is there a way to find out all concerned metadata (Custom fields, LWC/Aura/VF, Apex classes, triggers) used in the Lightning community?

I see errors telling me what I lack each time I push incomplete community metadata into the scratch org. But it only tells me one out of so many that I need to include.

Comment: From the documentation, we see that Network,CustomSite, ExperienceBundle are combined to define a community there is a package.xml file that could be of help for getting all the related things for a community in the documentation link https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_migrating_from_sandbox.htm&type=5 does this help?

Comment: Yes I have those included in my DX project. I would like to know about Apex Classes/Triggers, Custom fields, LWC/Aura/VF..., etc.